# Problema enviando formulario de contacto de página web a correo electrónico

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estoy tratando de que los datos del form de mi página web lleguen a mi correo y también a mi base de datos(efectivamente llega a la base de datos pero muchos no llegan al correo) para eso use php mailer así:

ahora, todo funciona bien siempre y cuando el usuario no envie en el form un correo gmail hotmail o qq mail en la variable $_POST["emailEspanol"], si el usuario rellena el campo con esa info el correo rebota y envie el siguiente error a mi correo.

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  jhonfed@gmail.com
    host smtp.mailchannels.net [52.36.255.115]
    SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
    550 5.7.1 [BFD] Sender prohibited by SPF
```

La pregunta es: ¿cómo podría corregir esto? o, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal para poder recibir toda la info del form en el correo?

```
<?php 
class MensajesController{

     #Enviar mensaje a la base de datos
     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    static public function registroMensajesController(){
        if(isset($_POST["nombresEspanol"])){

            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.,ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ?¿!¡]+$/',$_POST["nombresEspanol"]) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.,ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ?¿!¡]+$/', $_POST["apellidosEspanol"]) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.,ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ?¿!¡]+$/', $_POST["nombreEmpresaEspanol"]) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.,ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ?¿!¡]+$/', $_POST["paisEspanol"]) && preg_match('/^[A-z0-9\\._-]+@[A-z0-9][A-z0-9-]*(\\.[A-z0-9_-]+)*\\.([A-z]{2,6})$/', $_POST["emailEspanol"]) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.,ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ?¿!¡]+$/', $_POST["mensajeEspanol"])){



            #Enviar correo electrónico
            #-------------------------------------------------------------- 


            $envio = mail($correoDestino, $asunto, $mensaje, $cabecera);*/

             require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
                    date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");

                    $mail = new PHPMailer;

                    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

                    $mail->isMail();

                    $mail->setFrom($_POST["emailEspanol"]);

                    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST["emailEspanol"]);

                    $mail->Subject = "Mensaje de la web";

                    $mail->addAddress('jhond@gmail.com');

                     $mail->msgHTML('<p style="font-family:sans-serif">Nombres: '.$_POST["nombresEspanol"].'</p><p>Apellidos: '.$_POST["apellidosEspanol"].'<p><p>Empresa: '.$_POST["nombreEmpresaEspanol"].'</p><p>Pais:'.$_POST["paisEspanol"].'</p><p>Email: '.$_POST["emailEspanol"].' </p><br><p>Mensaje: <br><br>'.nl2br($_POST["mensajeEspanol"]).'</p>');

                     $envio = $mail->Send();    


            #Enviar suscriptor a la base de datos
            #-------------------------------------------------------------- 
            $datosController = array("nombresEspanol"=>trim($_POST["nombresEspanol"]),
                   "apellidosEspanol"=>trim($_POST["apellidosEspanol"]),
                   "nombreEmpresaEspanol"=>trim($_POST["nombreEmpresaEspanol"]), 
                    "paisEspanol"=>trim($_POST["paisEspanol"]),
                    "emailEspanol"=>trim($_POST["emailEspanol"]),
                    "mensajeEspanol"=>trim($_POST["mensajeEspanol"]));  

            $datosSuscriptor = $_POST["emailEspanol"];

            $revisarSuscriptor = MensajesModel::revisarSuscriptorModel($datosSuscriptor, "suscriptorespanol");

            $revisarSuscriptorForm = MensajesModel::revisarSuscriptorForm($datosSuscriptor, "suscriptorform");  

            if(empty($revisarSuscriptor) && empty($revisarSuscriptorForm)){ 

                MensajesModel::registroSuscriptoresModel($datosController, "suscriptorespanol");
            }


            #-------------Fin enviar suscriptor a la base de datos---------------------     

                $respuesta = MensajesModel::registroMensajesModel($datosController, "mensajesespanol");
                #si el mensaje se envio a el correo electronico y se guardo en la base de datos entonces
                echo $respuesta;
                if($envio && $respuesta == "ok"){
                             #muestreme una alerta diciendo que el mensaje se envio ecorrectamente
                             echo'<script>

                        swal({
                              title: "¡OK!",
                              text: "¡El mensaje ha sido enviado correctamente!",
                              type: "success",
                              confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                              closeOnConfirm: false
                        },

                        function(isConfirm){
                                 if (isConfirm) {      
                                    window.location = "Espanol";
                                  } 
                        });

                    </script>';
                         }else{

                            echo'<script>

                        swal({
                              title: "¡Oops!",
                              text: "¡No se pudo enviar el mensaje! Por favor contactanos por email whatsapp or facebook",
                              type: "warning",
                              confirmButtonText: "Close",
                              closeOnConfirm: false
                        },

                        function(isConfirm){
                                 if (isConfirm) {      
                                    window.location = "Espanol";
                                  } 
                        });

                    </script>';
                         }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Los dominios que tienen configuradas políticas SPF impiden que IPs no autorizadas realicen envíos de correo a nombre de esos dominios, así que no puedes usar como remitente sus direcciones de correo. Si quieres te puedo proponer alternativas.

Comment: si claro agradezco mucho su ayuda,estaba pensando en usar $mail->isSMTP(); para recibir en zohomail pero no tengo mucha idea la verdad

Comment: He redactado una respuesta explicando el problema que sufres y cómo tratar de solucionarlo (dos soluciones posibles). Espero que sea de ayuda y si tienes alguna duda no dudes en preguntar.

Answer (score 2):

### Descripción del problema

El problema que estás sufriendo se debe a las [políticas SPF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) de los dominios que estás incumpliendo en esta línea:

```
$mail->setFrom($_POST["emailEspanol"]);
```

No puedes enviar correo electrónico en nombre de un dominio externo si éste no te lo permite en su política SPF.

Para consultar la política SPF de un dominio puedes usar (en linux y windows):

```
nslookup -query=TXT <dominio>
```

Por ejemplo:

```
$ nslookup -query=TXT gmail.com
gmail.com   text = "v=spf1 redirect=_spf.google.com"
$ nslookup -query=TXT _spf.google.com
_spf.google.com text = "v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all"
$ nslookup -query=TXT _netblocks.google.com
_netblocks.google.com   text = "v=spf1 ip4:35.190.247.0/24 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:108.177.8.0/21 ip4:173.194.0.0/16 ip4:209.85.128.0/17 ip4:216.58.192.0/19 ip4:216.239.32.0/19 ~all"
_netblocks2.google.com  text = "v=spf1 ip6:2001:4860:4000::/36 ip6:2404:6800:4000::/36 ip6:2607:f8b0:4000::/36 ip6:2800:3f0:4000::/36 ip6:2a00:1450:4000::/36 ip6:2c0f:fb50:4000::/36 ~all"
_netblocks3.google.com  text = "v=spf1 ip4:172.217.0.0/19 ip4:172.217.32.0/20 ip4:172.217.128.0/19 ip4:172.217.160.0/20 ip4:172.217.192.0/19 ip4:108.177.96.0/19 ip4:35.191.0.0/16 ip4:130.211.0.0/22 ~all"
```

Como puedes ver Gmail reparte la configuración de su registro SPF en varios registros más a través de `include`, pero al final llegas a las direcciones IP o rangos de IP en las que se permite el envío de correos electrónicos en nombre de `gmail.com`.

---

### Soluciones propuestas

Una solución a tu problema es poner como remitente tu dirección de email o una permitida en tu servidor saliente y poner en `ReplyTo` la dirección que deseas para que cuando pulses en responder le envíes a él el correo:

```
$mail->setFrom('tudireccion@permitida.com');
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST["emailEspanol"]);
```

Otra solución sería configurar tu email permitido como remitente pero agregar como "texto a mostrar" (segundo parámetro de [`PHPMailer::setFrom()`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_setFrom)) la dirección del formulario para que, en apariencia, parezca que fue él quien te mandó el email:

```
$mail->setFrom('tudireccion@permitida.com', $_POST["emailEspanol"]);
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST["emailEspanol"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

hola Oscar pues deje de usar zohomail y cree una cuenta de correo desde el cpannel y ahora si puedo colocar en el setfrom $_POST["emailEspanol"] lo que ponga el usuario en el campo email ya sea hotmail gmail qq o cualquiera creo que el problema eran los registros mx. y ahora todos los datos del form llegan al correo nuevo

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

                    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

                    $mail->isMail();

                    $mail->setFrom($_POST["emailEspanol"]);

                    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST["emailEspanol"]);

                    $mail->Subject = "Mensaje de la web";

                    $mail->addAddress('info@example.com');
```

Comment: Si esto no es una respuesta no debe ir aquí, recuerda que esto **no es un foro** si tienes algo que decirle a quien te respondió entonces déjale un comentario o si la respuesta fue útil entonces acéptala